# Not able to download Transaction Attachment

Tags: corda

I am not able to download the attachments using below URLs with/from 
different corda Nodes/Ports , however i was able to download the same in earlier versions of corda i.e. below version 13 of corda.

http://localhost:10007/attachments/2A094563FBC6091F1E84D82EEDB48E6DB5F125E753F
http://localhost:10010/attachments/2A094563FBC6091F1E84D82EEDB48E6DB5F125E753F
http://localhost:10013/attachments/2A094563FBC6091F1E84D82EEDB48E6DB5F125E753F

Are there any changes made for this in corda version 14.0 for downloading of attachments. ??

note :- my transaction is getting shared with 3 parties with attachements but not able to download the attachements from all the nodes / URLS.

Please help , thanks in advance...

Comment: If it's possible, I would advise moving to v1. It has a different way of processing attachements (no longer via http to another node). There is an example here : https://github.com/ragmondo/cordaftp . I am just finishing up on the readme to make it easier to follow today .

Answer (score 0):

Dan Newton has a recent blog post on Corda attachments.

He outlines how you can use code to do it in kotlin

```
private val proxy: CordaRPCOps = rpc.proxy

@GetMapping("/{hash}")
fun downloadByHash(@PathVariable hash: String): ResponseEntity<Resource> {
  val inputStream = InputStreamResource(proxy.openAttachment(SecureHash.parse(hash)))
  return ResponseEntity.ok().header(
    HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
    "attachment; filename=\"$hash.zip\""
  ).body(inputStream)
}
```

He also outlines how to do it over HTTP if you have the corda attachmentID.

You can find the full post here: https://medium.com/corda/uploading-and-downloading-attachments-in-corda-7104a1e974c1